# Databinding a child combobox with a many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, c#-4.0, data-binding

Good Afternoon,

I'm attempting to implement the Entity Framework but seem to be having an issue when I'm trying to utilize a master-detail relationship.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to select a company from a combobox and then populate a subsequent combobox with a list of employee names for the selected company.  I seem to be running into issues trying to achieve this with a many-to-many relationship that has a bridge table containing some additional data.  The following is a simplified version of the three database tables I'm using:

```
create table Organization.Company
(
   CompanyID int not null,
   CompanyName varchar(40) not null,
   ServiceRepresentative varchar(20) not null,
   primary key (CompanyID)
)

create table Person.Employment
(
   CompanyID int not null,
   PersonID uniqueidentifier not null,
   EmployeeID int not null,
   FullTime bit not null,
   HoursPerWeek float null,
   primary key (CompanyID, PersonID),
   constraint fk_Company_Employment foreign key (CompanyID) references Organization.Company(CompanyID),
   constraint fk_Person_Employment foreign key (PersonID) references Person.ContactInfo(PersonID)
)

create table Person.ContactInfo
(
   PersonID uniqueidentifier not null,
   FirstName varchar(40) not null,
   LastName varchar(40) not null,
   primary key (PersonID)
)
```

Im my code-behind I have the following (WinForms):

```
    private orgEntities db;
    private BindingSource companyBinding;
    private BindingSource employeeBinding;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.db = new orgEntities();
        this.companyBinding = new BindingSource();
        this.employeeBinding = new BindingSource();

        this.companyBinding.DataSource = db.Companies.OrderBy(x => x.CompanyName);

        this.employeeBinding.DataSource = companyBinding;
        this.employeeBinding.DataMember = "Employment";

        this.currentCompanyComboBox.DataSource = companyBinding;
        this.currentCompanyComboBox.DisplayMember = "CompanyName";
        this.currentCompanyComboBox.ValueMember = "CompanyID";

        this.currentEmployeeComboBox.DataSource = employeeBinding;
        this.currentEmployeeComboBox.DisplayMember = "ContactInfo.FullName";  // Generated by extension class
        this.currentEmployeeComboBox.ValueMember = "PersonID";           
    }
```

The issue I seem to be running into is that only one employee is displayed inside the combobox when a company is selected.  When I change the "ContactInfo.FullName" to "EmployeeID" I get the full list of EmployeeIDs.  I'm assuming that the entity framework is grabbing the first person and navigating to their FullName property which causes their information to be the only thing displayed.

Is there any way I can get the full list of names to display in this drop-down with the bridge table (Person.Employment) present or would I be better off just creating a view of combining the Employment and ContactInfo tables together and using that in the edmx file rather than the two separate tables?

I understand that I may be going about this the wrong way and I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction on this one.  Thank you and have a great day!

Comment: `this.currentEmployeeComboBox.ValueMember = "CompanyID";` - `this.currentEmployeeComboBox.ValueMember = "PersonID";` - Check your Code. Is it true or just a copy failure?

Comment: Copy failure.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Is there any additional information that I could provide that would help anyone with assisting me?  If so, just let me know and I'd be happy to do so.